# CakePHP 3 - How do you patch associated data manually, and save all?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I perform a find to retrieve one entity and contain one of its associated entities, of which it hasMany.

The retrieved data looks like this in simple terms:

```
object(App\Model\Entity\Order) {

    'id' => '67839',
    'price' => (int) 100,
    'payment_instalments' => [
        (int) 0 => object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {

            'id' => (int) 43150,
            'order_id' => '67839',
            'amount' => (int) 100
        }
    ]
}
```

**I want to manually modify fields on the main entity and fields on the contained entity.**

I can modify the main entity easily like this:

```
$order = $orders->patchEntity($order, [
    'price' => 200
]);
```

The only way I could find of modifying the contained entity was to perform a separate patch on it. This can be done any number of ways. Here is one:

```
$instalments = TableRegistry::get('PaymentInstalments');
$instalment = $order->payment_instalments[0];
$order->payment_instalments[0] = $instalments->patchEntity(instalment , [
    'amount' => 200
]);
```

Then I want to save all:

```
$orders->save($order, ['associated' => 'PaymentInstalments']);
```

**The problem is the associated data does not get saved**, and the reason is because `$order->payment_instalments` does not get marked as "dirty" because it was patched separately. So the only solution I found was to manually mark it as dirty:

```
$order->dirty('payment_instalments', true);
```

Then the save will work.

This seems pretty messy to me, and would get a lot messier if I had to patch multiple contained entities. I couldn't find any documentation or help anywhere about how this is supposed to be done properly/elegantly.

**Is there a way to modify both the main entity and contained entities in one go, and have it automatically recognise that the contained data is dirty?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$order = $orders->patchEntity($order, [
    'price' => 123, // Change data on the order itself
    'payment_instalments' => [
        0 => [
            'id' => 43150,
            'amount' => 123,
        ]
    ]
]);
```

The `0 =>` part is optional, of course, in this case. I've put it in there to make it more clear that the data is in a nested array.

The reason why it's only saving the order itself and not the associated record is here:

```
'[dirty]' => [
    'price' => true
],
```

`payment_instalments` needs to be marked as dirty as well. That should happen automatically when you patch correctly.

Comment: The associated data is already in a nested array. The only way I could get it to work was by manually adding `$order->dirty('payment_instalments', true);` My changes are not being posted by a form, I am manually modifying the data, so what is the correct way of patching an associated entity in this instance (as it's not an array when you perform the find; it's an array of entities in `payment_instalments`).

Comment: @BadHorsie The correct way is shown here in the answer, that's exactly how you'd do it. The fact that the original property holds an array of entities is irrelevant, or let's better say it's actually required in order for the marshaller to be able to patch/merge the data properly.

Comment: @BadHorsie, when you try my code, what does the resulting `$order` look like? Note that it's vital that the `id` for the associated record is included in the data you pass to `patchEntity`, as that's how it will locate the entity that needs to be patched.

Comment: @ndm OK, I'm with you. So just modify the entities by providing data in array format, and the marshaller will merge it into the entities.